# Class Loading conflict using jboss/wildfly when two jars have same set of classes, how to set order/precedence?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, classloader

I have a war file which is to deployed on jboss/wildfly. The war contains a number of jars in its WEB-INF/lib directory. Some of these jars contain conflicting (or at least different ) versions of the same classes.

For example,
There is a jar of feign which are coming from two sources in our legacy code and defined in maven, so it might be used in one or the other classes and I can't delete any.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which brings Feign Dependency of feign-core:10.2.3

```
<dependency>
    <!-- Required to use PATCH -->
    <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>8.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which brings Feign Dependency of feign-core:8.18.0

Both has a Response Class but one of them doesn't have a specific **create** method required by code.

The question is when jboss/wildfly deploys this war file it will bring all dependencies in WEB-INF/lib folder and both jars are there only, what will be the order/precedence of the jar files here? If classloader picks the first jar, it will throw an error, otherwise it will work correctly.

In the first case it throws this error:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: feign.Response.create(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Lfeign/Response$Body;)Lfeign/Response;**

How can we avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Maven will not pack both versions of `feign-core` into the WAR except in the case that the groupId changed. Maven will always pick only one version for a given groupId and artifactId.

Generally you should try to make it work with the newer version. I this is not possible, you can think about using the Maven shade plugin for shading.

Comment: It is packing....all the feign jars are there...                                                                         
 feign-core-10.2.3.jar  feign-form-3.8.0.jar         feign-gson-8.18.0.jar        feign-hystrix-10.2.3.jar  feign-slf4j-10.2.3.jar
feign-core-8.18.0.jar  feign-form-spring-3.8.0.jar  feign-httpclient-8.18.0.jar  feign-okhttp-10.1.0.jar

Comment: and its also packing because they are coming from different sources...one from io.github.openfeign and other from com.netflix.feign

Comment: So they probably have different groupIds which is why Maven considers them to be different. So I would try to exclude the older version, or if not possible, try to shade the classes.

Comment: The problem is that both the jars are required in one or the other forms. Our code has been using this since long and it used to pick right jar but suddenly it has started using the faulty jar. Is it something concerning with jboss class loading precedence? That's the question. Or any jboss property which keeps one jar above the other?

Comment: Having overlapping classes is like gambling. I may or may not work, and it is best to avoid this.

Comment: I agree, but I think there must be some reason that it was loading earlier successfully and now it's not loading in the manner it should.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it worth looking into this.